# Delete an item from Redux state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm wondering if you could help me with this problem if possible. I am trying to delete an item from the Redux state. I have passed in the ID of the item that the user clicks via `action.data` into the reducer.

I'm wondering how I can match the `action.data` with one of the ID's within the Redux state and then remove that object from the array? I am also wondering the best way to then set the new state after the individual object has been removed?

Please see the code below:

```
export const commentList = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_COMMENT':
      let newComment = { comment: action.data, id: +new Date };
      return state.concat([newComment]);
    case 'DELETE_COMMENT':
      let commentId = action.data;

    default:
      return state || [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Just filter the comments:

```
case 'DELETE_COMMENT':
  const commentId = action.data;
  return state.filter(comment => comment.id !== commentId);
```

This way you won't mutate the original `state` array, but return a new array without the element, which had the id `commentId`.

To be more concise:

```
case 'DELETE_COMMENT':
  return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.data);
```

Comment: I saw another example which used just id, as opposed to your answer ({ id }). what is the different here?

Comment: @MattSaunders `({ id }) => ...` is a lambda expression (arrow function in js terms), which destructures it's argument. Meaning the input should be an object, and we are only interested in it's `id` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: What to do if it was I had change an object within array that is within in the array of objects. `lists: [{name: 'xyz', cards: [{...}]}...many more lists]`

Comment: Doesn’t .filter() return a new array, therefore reassigning the entire state of your application?

Comment: @Shah that's the point of redux. You return a new state each time your reducer's called instead of mutating an existing state. Filter won't clone what's inside the array just the array structure itself. So in case you have complex objects in the array, they will be kept the same, just put in a new array.

Comment: My mistake I didn't realize .filter() was a shallow copy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Object.assign(target, ...sources)` and spread all the items that don't match the action id

```
case "REMOVE_ITEM": {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    items: [...state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)],
  });
}
```

Comment: the spread operator is a ES6 syntax feature. I'm not sure why you're using Object.assign in this example alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Try this approach.

```
case "REMOVE_ITEM": 
  return {
  ...state,
    comment: [state.comments.filter(comment => comment.id !== action.id)]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a state set as an Object instead of an Array:

I used reduce() instead of filter() to show another implementation. But ofc, it's up to you how you choose to implement it.

```
/*
//Implementation of the actions used:

export const addArticle = payload => {
    return { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload };
};
export const deleteArticle = id => {
     return { type: DELETE_ARTICLE, id}
*/

export const commentList = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ARTICLE:
        return {
            ...state,
            articles: [...state.articles, action.payload]
        };
    case DELETE_ARTICLE: 
        return {
            ...state,
            articles: state.articles.reduce((accum, curr) => {
                if (curr.id !== action.id) {
                    return {...accum, curr};
                } 
                return accum;
            }, {}), 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case filter worked without () and {} and the state was updated

```
case 'DELETE_COMMENT':
    return state.filter( id  => id !== action.data);
```