# Deleting Object in Redux State with Id in Lodash/Javascript

Tags: object, redux, state, store, lodash

I'm referring to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777525/delete-an-item-from-redux-state) on removing an unwanted ID from a redux state. My state is set up slightly differently and I'm not sure how to use lodash to filter it.

My array:

```
[
  {id:1, animal:fish, name:bob}, 
  {id:2, animal:dig,name:jim}, 
  {id:3,animal:cat, name:Tk} 
]
```

This is my offending code (I'm passing the ID as the action.payload):

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { animals:[]};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_ANIMAL:
        let animalId = action.data;
        return {...state, animals: [...state.filter(c => c.id !== animalId)]; 
  }
  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use lodash for this. Just filter the animals array:

```
case DELETE_ANIMAL:
        let animalId = action.data;
        return {...state, animals: state.animals.filter(c => c.id !== animalId)}
```